# Deserialize a Realm object containing other Realm objects with GSON?

Tags: android, gson, realm

I have an entity, Employee:

```
public class Employee extends RealmObject implements Serializable {
    @PrimaryKey
    @SerializedName("id") public long id;

    @SerializedName("name") public String firstName;
    @SerializedName("lastName") public String lastName;
    @SerializedName("profilePictureSmall") public String profilePictureSmallUrl;
    @SerializedName("contact") public Contact contact;
}

public class Contact extends RealmObject implements Serializable {
    @PrimaryKey
    @SerializedName("id") public long id;

    @SerializedName("workMail") public String workEmail;
    ... Some other fields ...
}
```

When deserializing `Employee` from json, all `String` fields and `long` field are deserialized properly, but my `contact` field is left `null`.

I've tried writing a custom deserializer for Employee:

```
public class DeserializeEmployee implements JsonDeserializer<Employee> {
    @Override
    public Employee deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        Log.d(TAG, "Deserializing Employee");
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        JsonObject o = json.getAsJsonObject();
        employee.id = o.get("id").getAsLong();
        employee.firstName = o.get("name").getAsString();
        employee.lastName = o.get("lastName").getAsString();
        employee.profilePictureSmallUrl = o.get("profilePictureSmall").getAsString();
        employee.contact = context.deserialize(o.get("contact"), Contact.class);
        return employee;
    }
}
```

and a custom deserializer for Contact:

```
public class DeserializeContact implements JsonDeserializer<Contact> {
    @Override
    public Contact deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        Log.d(TAG, "Deserializing Contact");
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        JsonObject o = json.getAsJsonObject();
        contact.id = o.get("id").getAsLong();
        contact.workEmail = o.get("workMail").getAsString();
        return contact;
    }
}
```

I've also registered them both:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, (JsonSerializer<Date>) (src, typeOfSrc, context) -> new JsonPrimitive(src.getTime()))
                .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, (JsonDeserializer<Date>) (json, typeOfT, context) -> new Date(json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsLong()))
                .registerTypeAdapter(Contact.class, new DeserializeContact())
                .registerTypeAdapter(Employee.class, new DeserializeEmployee())
                .create();
```

My Employee deserializer is called and its primitive fields are set  properly, but my Contact deserializer isn't called at all, and field `contact` is therefore `null`.

JSON:

```
{
  "id": 5,
  "name": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "profilePictureSmall": "http://example.com/fjlsjf",
  "contact": {
     "id": 9,
     "workMail": "johndoe@gmail.com"
  }
}
```

**Edit** Added sample json if somebody needs, but pretty sure it isn't the problem.

Comment: do you have a scheme for this json?

Comment: @ste9206 Added sample json.

Comment: @MarkoStojanovic Just curious: why do you need custom (de)serializers? Gson can do the same out of box with higher efficiency (it uses streaming in type adapters rather than fully-in-memory JSON trees that are used in (de)serializers). + Note that having a custom (de)serializer disables the built-in type adapters thus your `@SerializedName` annotations have no effect.

Comment: @MarkoStojanovic why don't you use JsonReader?

Comment: @MarkoStojanovic I could post an example of a JsonReader if you are interested

Comment: @ste9206 No need, thanks. Realm and Gson go along nicely after I actually send proper data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was sending wrong JSON from the server, which didn't include `contact` field. When I've actually sent proper data, everything worked, even without custom deserializers. Sorry for wasting everyone's time.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
employeeObject = realm.copyFromRealm(employeeObject);
```